# POWERSHELL script to move only files with numeric digits (within the filename) in common

Tags: powershell, filenames, get-childitem

I was helped in the past few days to find a POWERSHELL script that would help me move only files that had the first 8 characters in common.

The script is the one below and it works perfectly

```
$destination_folder = "C:\TEMP\DESTINATION"
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TEMP\ORIGIN" -File -Force -Recurse
$filelist|Group-Object -Property {$_.basename.Substring(0,8)}|Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
ForEach-Object {$_.Group  | Move-Item -Destination $destination_folder}
```

What I would like, and what would help me a lot, is to modify the above script in such a way that files that have at least 8 numeric characters in common are moved (even if they are not at the beginning of the name) so that the search is performed on the entire file name and not only on the first 8 characters.

Do you think it is possible to obtain such a result?

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Do you have a sample list of file names and resulting groups?

Comment: @BoogaRoo Yes, the numbers are contiguos but not always at the begin of the filename; sometimes they could be at the end (randomfile12345678.pdf) , sometimes in the middle (random12345678file.pdf) or sometimes at the begin (12345678randomfile.pdf).
Thank you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen a sample lists of the files with which I have to work are the same reported in my comment above addressed to BoogaRoo.
Is it enough or do you need more information?
Thank you

Comment: this >>> `[regex]::Match('asdf1234567890987654321asdf' -replace '[^\d]', '\d{8}').Value` <<< will give you the 1st 8 chars of any digits in the string.

Comment: So, just in case it was not 100% clear, to Implement Lee solution above you just do `$filelist | Group-Object -Property {  [regex]::Match($_.BaseName -replace '[^\d]', '\d{8}').Value} | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1} ` ... I deleted my answer since his answer is way more elegant and ultimately put mine to shame.

Comment: Thanks to you all!
your suggestions let me complete my script :)
As suggested from @SagePourpre I would like to assign the answer to the Lee_Dailey solution.

Thanks once again!

Comment: @mklement0 - done! i had problems describing what was doing things ... so i would not object at all to some help with that. [*grin*]

Comment: @AndreaMorresi - please take a look at the Answer i posted. if you need it to be more specific to your general problem ... please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

since your specific Question is about getting the needed digits from a string, this is how how to do that one thing.

the code ...

```
[regex]::Match('asdf1234567890987654321asdf' -replace '\D', '^\d{8}').Value
```

output = `12345678`

what the code does ...

- `[regex]::Match(`
  uses the regex type accelerator to call the match static method of that type.
- `'asdf1234567890987654321asdf' -replace '\D'`
  this derives the string for the Match call to use. it strips out the non-digit chars by replacing them with nothing at all.
- `, '^\d{8}'`
  this is the pattern for the Match call to use on the above string. it grabs the 1st 8 chars of the resulting replacement string.
  ***please note that this will cause your `Group-Object` call to work on a `.BaseName` that has more than 8 digits ... not just on those that have exactly 8 digits.***
- `).Value`
  grabs the string in the `.Value` property of the object form the previous `[regex]::Match()` call

you will want to replace that silly example string with the `.BaseName` from your fileinfo object.